# Difference in tweets received by streamR and twitteR packages in R

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to retrieve tweets based on a particular word from twitter. I have used both twitteR and streamR packages in R.

For accessing tweets using twitteR I use `searchTwitter("love", n=50)` whereas when I use streamR package I use `filterStream("tweets.json", track = c("love"), timeout = 30,  oauth = my_oauth)`

However for almost all the search terms I have tried with, searchTwitter returns a lot more tweets whereas filterStream isn't able to get that many.

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `timeout = 30` option is most likely the culprit here. `filterStream()` accesses the Twitter streaming API for the duration specified in the `timeout` option. From the `searchR` [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/streamR/streamR.pdf) of `timeout`:

> numeric, maximum length of time (in seconds) of connection to stream. 
>   The connection will be automatically closed after this period.  For
>   example, setting timeout to 10800 will keep the connection open for 3
>   hours.  The default is 0, which will keep the connection open
>   permanently

That means that `filterStream` with `timeout = 30` option listens to the Twitter stream for 30 seconds.

`searchTwitter()` on the other hand searches the Twitter history available in the API ([6-9 days](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)) up until the maximum number of tweets as specified in the `n=50` option. So this should result in 50 tweets.

The `streamR` and `twitteR` packages are meant for different things: http://pablobarbera.com/blog/archives/1.html If you want to access the stream, use `streamR`, if you want to access Twitter history use the `twitteR` package. Both packages complement each other.

Comment: I am aware of that. However with searchtwitter I get 50 tweets within 5 seconds or so..whereas with filterStream at times no tweets arrive or just very few come.

Comment: Yes, `searchTwitter` does not listen to the API stream, but searches the Twitter history. `filterStream` accesses the *stream* and if no one in the world writes about "love" within 30 seconds (what a sad world!), you get no results. The two commands access different things (searchTwitter = Twitter history, filterStream = current Twitter stream). Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: Oh thanks! is there any function in streamR package which does similar to searchTwitter?

Comment: No. The `streamR` and `twitteR` are meant for different things: http://pablobarbera.com/blog/archives/1.html As I said, if you want to access the stream, use `streamR`, if you want to access Twitter history use `twitteR` package. Both packages complement each other. I've added this information to the answer above, to make it more clear.